# Regular Expression to Match Exact Word - Search String Highlight

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following 2 methods to highlight the search keywords. It is working fine but fetching partial words also.

For Example:

Text:  "This is .net Programming"
Search Key Word: "is"

It is highlighting partial word from th**is** and "is"

Please let me know the correct regular expression to highlight the correct match.

```
private string HighlightSearchKeyWords(string searchKeyWord, string text)
{
    Regex exp = new Regex(@", ?");
    searchKeyWord = "(\b" + exp.Replace(searchKeyWord, @"|") + "\b)";
    exp = new Regex(searchKeyWord, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return exp.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(MatchEval));
}

private string MatchEval(Match match)
{
    if (match.Groups[1].Success)
    {
        return "<span class='search-highlight'>" + match.ToString() + "</span>";
    }
    return ""; //no match
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really just need @ before your "(\b" and "\b)" because the string "\b" will not be "\b" as you would expect. But I have also tried making another version with a replacement pattern instead of a full-blown method.

How about this one:

```
private string keywordPattern(string searchKeyword)
{
    var keywords = searchKeyword.Split(',').Select(k => k.Trim()).Where(k => k != "").Select(k => Regex.Escape(k));

    return @"\b(" + string.Join("|", keywords) + @")\b";
}

private string HighlightSearchKeyWords(string searchKeyword, string text)
{
    var pattern = keywordPattern(searchKeyword);
    Regex exp = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    return exp.Replace(text, @"<span class=""search-highlight"">$0</span>");
}
```

Usage:

```
var res = HighlightSearchKeyWords("is,this", "Is this programming? This is .net Programming.");
```

Result:

```
<span class="search-highlight">Is</span> <span class="search-highlight">this</span> programming? <span class="search-highlight">This</span> <span class="search-highlight">is</span> .net Programming.
```

**Updated** to use \b and a simplified replace pattern. (The old one used (^|\s) instead of the first \b and ($|\s) instead of the last \b. So it would also work on search terms which not only includes word-characters.

**Updated** to your comma notation for search terms

**Updated** forgot Regex.Escape - added now. Otherwise searches for "\w" would blow up the thing :)

**Updated** do to a comment ;)

Comment: Instead of what? he has a , notation so the keywords should be split up like: "\bthis|is\b".

Comment: stackuser1 -> :) But see my last update. Escaping input data is really important to do otherwise your users can break the thing :/

Comment: It will match false positives if you search with multiple keywords. `HighlightSearchKeyWords("is, blah", "This is .net Programming.") will match both Th*is* and *is*!

Comment: @Jaroslav I just tried HighlightSearchKeyWords("is,blah", "This is .net Programming."). It works fine?

Comment: @lasseespeholt: switch it up: "blah,is". Also, you won't be able to separate the values with comma and whitespace.

Comment: True, but actually it has to be "blah,is" ;)

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Yeah, I have edited the comment after I tried with a compiler ( can't be sure when you compile in your head :-D). Btw. the OP specifically asked that it should not highlight the partial keywords.

Comment: @Jaroslav hehe, it did not most of the time :D I have introduced another method to do the keyword pattern now. But the one you have has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fixed line:

```
searchKeyWord = @"(\b" + exp.Replace(searchKeyWord, @"|") + @"\b)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the keywords in a non-matching group, otherwise you will get **false positives** (if you are using multiple keywords separated by commas as indicated in the sample)!

```
private string EscapeKeyWords(string searchKeyWord)
{
    string[] keyWords = searchKeyWord.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < keyWords.Length; i++) keyWords[i] = Regex.Escape(keyWords[i].Trim());

    return String.Join("|", keyWords);
}

private string HighlightSearchKeyWords(string searchKeyWord, string text)
{
    searchKeyWord = @"(\b(?:" + EscapeKeyWords(searchKeyWord) + @")\b)";
    Regex exp = new Regex(searchKeyWord, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return exp.Replace(text, @"<span class=""search-highlight"">$0</span>");
}
```

Comment: Try this one: HighlightSearchKeyWords("  blah  ,,  is  ", "This is .net Programming.") ;) lots of spans. You need to remove empty entities.

Comment: +1 Thanks for highlighting some issues in my code which you show a solution to.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: You are right. Whitespaces should not be allowed. The solution is trivial.