# Match and highlight keywords from list in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to scan a text string for any words contained in a list and highlight all matches found in the string regardless of occurrences using regexp in C#. Would someone point me right direction? Sorry for sounding non-technical but hope it makes sense.

For eg:

List contains "Match","matches", "list", "text"

string text =  "Match all matches from the list in text and highlight the matches"

Output: "**Match** all **matches** from the **list** in **text** and highlight the **matches**"

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: When you say regardless of occurrences, you mean it's ok if the word appears in the middle of another word?  For example, `list` would still match `blister`?

Comment: Honestly this is too vague and no one on here is going to answer this. You need to think about how to break down a string and compare it to the list. Time and persistence will win the day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? any code examples, we aren't here to program for you we're here to help.

Comment: It needs to match exact words and no sub-strings/ partial matches. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Again, this is really not hard to do. You need to attempt this first and then if you are not getting results post your code to this site. So, go find your chapter on Strings and start working with the functions available to you.

Comment: Joshua Oglesbee.. Thanks for your suggestion but I'm going to go with mellamokb and give him the credits for his kindness on offering me an insight into the solution. Thanks very much mellamokb!!!You were really helpful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to Match Exact Word - Search String Highlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414556/regular-expression-to-match-exact-word-search-string-highlight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of search words:

```
var searches = new [] { "Match", "matches", "list", "text" };
```

and a string to search:

```
var text = "Match all matches from the list in text and highlight the matches";
```

You can combine the words into a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) that searches first or second or third, etc, by combining them with [**String.Join**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (The `\b` denotes a word boundary so only whole words match):

```
var regex = @"\b(" + String.Join("|", searches) + @")\b";
// regex: \b(Match|matches|list|text)\b
```

Then it's a simple matter of applying the search and using a replace to highlight (in a replace expression, `$1` is a reference to the first matched group, e.g., the word that was found in the original phrase):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, regex, @"**$1**");
// result: **Match** all **matches** from the **list** in **text** and highlight the **matches**
```

([**Code Demo**](http://ideone.com/tehHiO))

Note that this solution works fine for the example you gave, but there are a number of caveats depending on what your real-world scenario looks like:

- If your search "words" have special characters recognized by Regex, you may have to escape them, e.g., `\.`,`\(`, `\)`, etc.
- The current code example provided above is case-sensitive, so for example `Match` would *not* match `match`.